# How to align font-awesome icons to center

Tags: html, css

I want to make the icons to be arranged in a row with center align.

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjs96/tyhxmf3z/1/)

```css
.ft-foot {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: #000;
}
.inclusion {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inclusion span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inclusion i {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="ft-foot">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Guide</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Site seeing</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Hotels</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Transportation</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Food</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: They are center aligned in your fiddle?

Comment: I checked http://jsfiddle.net/sjs96/tyhxmf3z/1/ and icons are in center of row

Comment: actually i want all these one another in a row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` in `li`

```css
.ft-foot {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: #000;
    text-align:center;
}
.ft-foot ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 10px;
}
.inclusion {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inclusion span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="ft-foot">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Guide</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Site seeing</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Hotels</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Transportation</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Food</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to the li elemets and set the ul parent to `text-align: center`.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wemsm7me/

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center` in `ul` and `display: inline-block` in `li`.

```css
.ft-foot {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: #000;
}
.inclusion {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inclusion span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inclusion i {
  font-size: 30px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="ft-foot">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Guide</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Site seeing</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Hotels</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Transportation</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Food</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ft-foot {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: #000;
}
.inclusion {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inclusion span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inclusion i {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.ft-foot ul{
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
.ft-foot ul li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```